# Join by condition and date matching

Tags: sql, sql-server

The  goal is to understand which manager provides the client's order without grouping by the managers. It's important, that during the time, clients' managers are changing, and that may happen several times, including returnee to the previous manager.

We have an `Orders` table:

| Client | Order Date | Order Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cl.1 | 01/01/22 | 120 |
| Cl.2 | 01/01/22 | 450 |
| Cl.3 | 02/01/22 | 340 |
| Cl.4 | 10/01/22 | 210 |
| Cl.1 | 05/02/22 | 119 |
| Cl.2 | 07/02/22 | 454 |
| Cl.3 | 08/02/22 | 342 |
| Cl.4 | 11/02/22 | 225 |

We have a `Managers` changing table:

| Client | Manager Change Date | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cl.3 | 01/01/22 | Mng.2 |
| Cl.4 | 08/01/22 | Mng.3 |
| Cl.2 | 07/02/22 | Mng.2 |
| Cl.3 | 06/02/22 | Mng.1 |
| Cl.1 | 15/02/22 | Mng.2 |

The default manager at the start is Mng.1.

The result table is `Orders` table + Manager column:

| Client | Order Date | Order Amount | Manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cl.1 | 01/01/22 | 120 | Mng.1 |
| Cl.2 | 01/01/22 | 450 | Mng.1 |
| Cl.3 | 02/01/22 | 340 | Mng.2 |
| Cl.4 | 10/01/22 | 210 | Mng.3 |
| Cl.1 | 05/02/22 | 119 | Mng.1 |
| Cl.2 | 07/02/22 | 454 | Mng.2 |
| Cl.3 | 08/02/22 | 342 | Mng.1 |
| Cl.4 | 11/02/22 | 225 | Mng.3 |

Comment: It's typically best to show what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work. Otherwise it looks like you are just trying to get other people to do your homework for you.

Comment: I used **left outer join** function, but the we result was not as expected. Thank you, next time will provide my code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by m.Client, o.OrderDate order by o.ClientDate desc) as rn,
        coalesce(m.Manager, 'Mng.1') as AssignedManager
    from Orders o left outer join Managers m
        on m.Client = o.Client and m.ClientDate <= o.OrderDate
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

Comment: That is not the demanded result.

| Clinet | Order Date | Order Amount |m |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- |-------------- |
| Cl.2 | 2022-02-07 |454 |1           |
| Cl.3 | 2022-02-08            |342 |1            |
| Cl.4 | 2022-02-11 |225 |1            |

Comment: I received only 4 rows. That is not correct. row_number didn't do a benefit. I changed the code, expelled where 

`with data as (
 select 
  o.[Client]
  ,o.[Order Date]
  ,o.[Order Amount]
  ,row_number() over (partition by o.Client order by o.[Order Date] desc) as rn
  ,coalesce(m.Manager, 'Mng.1') as AssignedManager
 from [Orders] o left outer join [Managers] m
 on m.Client = o.Client and m.[Manager Change Date] <= o.[Order Date]
)
select * from data --where rn = 1;`


The result is 9 rows, one more, than the goal result. The 7th row, with Cl.3 / 2022.02.08 / Mng.2 is incorrect

Comment: Try my update. You don't have an order id so I'm using the date.

Comment: With the new updated code we are missing the **Cl.2 / 2022-01-01 / 450 / 2 / Mng.1** order(

Comment: Try again. We need client and date.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked and I caught the logic)
@shawnt00 Thank you for your time and efforts!